# Submit same app with different name and graphics theme

Tags: android, google-play

I have a game in Android app store.  I am thinking of updating its theme mainly graphics and submitting the app with different name. Behind the scene code remains the same. Current game is very generic and my idea is to make it a brand and target one particular segment. Is it fine or Google may find some issues with this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a [developer centric question about application stores](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Play Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> **Spam and Placement in the Store**
>
> Developers are important partners in
> maintaining a great user experience on Google Play.
>
> - **Do not post repetitive content.**

Comment: How about if I unlist the previous game and upload the new one.  Also how does angry bird comes up different theme based on same game  philosophy

Comment: As far as I know, Angry Birds has distinctly different levels, not just different themes. Angry Birds Space even has different physics. If you're purely changing the theme/look, you're repetitive. If you offer the same (or similar) games with distinctively different gameplay, you're probably ok.